# VBA Excel, Permanently Save/Update Textbox Input

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

How would you save or update a TextBox with its own value the user has inputted?

Example, I have a Userform with a TextBox for "password". Every user who opens the file will enter his own password in that TextBox, then save the file and reopen at any given time.

Note, the value should be saved permanently in that file (not only session based), so even after completely closing and reopening the file, the users password should be there in the Textbox until its changed again.

Passing the value to cell isn't a good idea, since its a password and shouldn't be visible.

I used so far below code, to no avail.

**In the UF code for "Save" button:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    SavePWStrings
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

**In the standard module:**

```
Public Sub SavePWStrings()
Dim pw As String
    pw = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
    UserForm1.TextBox1 = pw
End Sub
```

Goal is to update the value of the TextBox programmatically as below.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: There's no native way of saving textbox values directly. The easiest way is to store them in a cell. If you're worried about casual users seeing them, make the sheet "veryhidden". Alternatives are writing the values to a database (a lot more work); or storing them in CustomDocumentProperties.

Comment: xlSheetVeryHidden  is enough to prevent savvy sneakers form unhiding them?  Of course workbook code will be locked by password. Security is a big concern in my case.

Comment: Why don't you encript the passwords also for extra security?

Comment: Encrypting is a good idea, but I dont know which route to go...
Even CustomDocumentProperties is readily visible under advanced properties.

Comment: It is possible. Store each user details in a module at runtime. (Yeah you heard it right). Slightly difficult but achievable...

Comment: @Siddharth Rout you mean updating a VBA variable in the code with the TextBox value? I'd love to see that. Any link?

Comment: No link as such. Just google "VBA read text from module" and "VBA write text to module" :)

Comment: One question though. Where will you get the username from? Is there a textbox? or you are getting it from `Environ("Username")`?

Comment: xlSheetVeryHidden will prevent casual users from seeing the data. Putting a password on your VBA code will prevent more technical users from finding the name of your sheet and un-hiding it. However there's nothing you can do in Excel to prevent super-technical people from removing the password. If you're worried about that level of attack, Excel isn't the right platform for you.

Comment: "Security is a big concern in my case" Well, writing the login data to a database is probably the "safest". I can also recommend digitally signing the VBA project. Locked Excel files, hidden sheets and VBA projects are quite easily cracked, by using a digital certificate, you cannot control if the file gets breached, but you will know when the code has been edited as certificates are removed due to tampering. At least that is what i was told. Excel is not really designed with security in mind.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01

Comment: Ok I managed to create a sample code which can read/write to a module but you need to first answer my above question... Where will you get the username from? Is there a textbox? or you are getting it from Environ("Username")?

Comment: @Siddharth well username (not environ) can be stored in a cell of a very hidden sheet, but password comes with security concerns.  I wish there is a way to actively update variables inside vba code with TextBox input so it will be there permanent.

Comment: Ok if I show you an exmaple using environ for username, will you be able to take it from there? all you will have to do is get that value from the cell

Comment: That will work. As said in my case its not from Environ but from another Textbox, but I can manage that part

Comment: gimme 30 mins max to post an answer. will try and include screenshots and some explanation

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, here is an unusual way to achieve what you want. You can store the username/password in the module.

**Module Setup**

Insert a Module. Let's call it `MyModule`. Paste the below code there

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserDatabase()
    'USER|sid_sid_sid|PASSWORD
    '
    '
    '
End Sub
```

[image]

NOTE: Not that it matters but to make it look concise and manageable, ensure that there are no blank lines after `End Sub`.

`|sid_sid_sid|` is a separator that I am using to seperate the user from the password. Feel free to change that. Ensure that it is a unique text.

**Userform Setup**

And let's say your userform looks like this

[image]

Paste this code in the userform code area. The name of the textbox is `txtPassword`

```
Option Explicit

Dim proj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim comp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim codeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim lineCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim doNotReEnter As Boolean
Dim oldPassword As String
Dim newPassword As String

'~~> Separator for Username / Password
Private Const MySep As String = "|sid_sid_sid|"

'~~> Userform Initialize Event
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim currentUser As String

    '~~> Get the username
    currentUser = Environ("UserName")

    lblUser.Caption = "USER :" & currentUser

    '~~> Check if user exists
    If DoesUserExist(currentUser) Then
        '~~> If it does then get the password
        txtPassword.Text = GetUserPassword(currentUser)
        oldPassword = txtPassword.Text '<~~ Store current password in a variable
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Login button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '~~> Get the password from the textbox
    newPassword = txtPassword.Text

    '~~> Check if they match. If they do then do not store else store
    If newPassword <> oldPassword And Len(Trim(newPassword)) <> 0 Then
        Dim modLine As String

        modLine = "    '" & Environ("UserName") & MySep & txtPassword.Text

        Set proj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
        Set comp = proj.VBComponents("MyModule")
        Set codeMod = comp.CodeModule
        codeMod.InsertLines codeMod.CountOfLines - 1, modLine
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if the user is there in the module
Private Function DoesUserExist(xlUser As String) As Boolean
    Set proj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    Set comp = proj.VBComponents("MyModule")
    Set codeMod = comp.CodeModule

    lineCount = codeMod.CountOfLines

    For i = 1 To lineCount
        If codeMod.Find(xlUser, i, 1, -1, -1) Then
            DoesUserExist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function

'~~> Function to get the password for a user
Private Function GetUserPassword(xlUser As String) As String
    Set proj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    Set comp = proj.VBComponents("MyModule")
    Set codeMod = comp.CodeModule

    lineCount = codeMod.CountOfLines

    For i = 1 To lineCount
        If codeMod.Find(xlUser, i, 1, -1, -1) Then
            GetUserPassword = Split(codeMod.Lines(i, 1), MySep)(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

**Basic Setup**

1. In VBE, click on TOOLS|REFERENCES and check the `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3` as shown below

   [image]
2. Enable trust access to the VBA project object model. Click FILE | OPTIONS. In the navigation pane, select TRUST CENTER. Click TRUST CENTER SETTINGS. In the navigation pane, select MACRO SETTINGS. Ensure that `Trust access to the VBA project object model` is checked. Click OK.

   [image]
3. Now if you notice that this will work when the VBA Project is Unprotected. So how do we make it work when the VBA project is Locked. For that, use the code from [HERE](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?43809-Project-locked-for-viewing-SendKeys). Port all that code inside the userform and do not keep that code in the module.
4. For additional security, you can encrypt the data before storing it in a module. Lot of examples in the web on how to encrypt/decrypt a string in VBA.

---

For demonstration purpose, I have VBA unlocked.

[image]

Sample File: The file can be downloaded from [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg2yrko7yk67pvh/Read-Write%20to%20VBE.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks for the fascinating detailed post! I'll test and advise.

Comment: Definitely a great starting point!  So on initial test... before modifying the UF and code to accommodate another TextBox for Username, I noticed two issues a) it retrieves the first password from the list, not the latest (last). b) it writes a record even if the same password already exists for that user.  In the code it does look like it supposed to prevent this but it doesn't.